# Handle the result of a AsynTask in an android application

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've an android application.

I need to execute a code on a separate task because it fives me android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException .

**This is my code:**

```
 public class AccesoCuentaActivity extends Activity{
   public void validacion(View v) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException
{
    try {
    String usuario=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsu)).getText().toString();
    String pass=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass)).getText().toString();
    String[] pars = new String[2];

             String[] = new String[2];
             pars[0] = usuario;
    pars[1] = pass;
            new ValidacionThread().execute(pars);
             Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("idBoton",12);
    intent.putExtra("usuario",usu);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);          

} }
```

**Task:**

```
public class ValidacionThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Usuario> {

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://webservices.pcp/";
    private final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/webServices/pcpWS?wsdl";
    private final String SOAPACTION = "";
    private final String METHOD = "ValidarUsuario";

    protected Usuario doInBackground(String[] pars) {

               String user = pars[0];
               String password = pars[1];
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD); 
                SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                sobre.dotNet = false;       
                request.addProperty("login", user);        
                request.addProperty("password", password); 
                sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);        
                try {
                    transporte.call(SOAPACTION, sobre);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SoapObject resultado = null;
                try {
                    resultado = (SoapObject)sobre.getResponse();
                } catch (SoapFault e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Usuario usu = new Usuario();
                usu.IdUsuario= resultado.getProperty(0).toString();
                usu.Nombre = resultado.getProperty(1).toString();
                usu.Apellidos = resultado.getProperty(2).toString();
                usu.Rol = resultado.getProperty(3).toString();   
                usu.Centro=resultado.getProperty(4).toString();
                return usu;     

}
       protected void  onPostExecute(ValidacionThread vt) {

        }
}
```

It gives me two problems:

1) In class AccesoCuentaActivity :

I want to save the variable "usuario" return in **ValidationThread.doInBackground()**. But how do I do it?

Indeed if I just write: new **ValidacionThread().execute(pars);** it tells me that the variable "usu" (intent.putExtra("usuario",usu);) has not been initialized

while with code (in main code) **Usuario usu = new ValidacionThread().execute(pars);** it says **type mismatch**

2) In `doInBackground()` line eclipse gives the **warning**:
Varargs methods should only override or be overridden by other varargs methods unlike `ValidacionThread.doInBackground(String[])` and `AsyncTask<String,Void,Usuario>.doInBackground(String...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is Async task you need to create a return way for that data.
I would recomend creating an interface like:

`interface{ 
     public void parseData(Usuario data);
    }`

and implementing it in your activity class.

I would then pass and instance of activity to that async task in constructor.

Then in your ValidationThread:

`protected void  onPostExecute(Usuario vt) {
        activityInstance.parseData(vt);
        }`

As for the second part change String[] to String..